# How to generate classes from multiple WSDL files using jaxb

Tags: java, spring-boot, soap, jaxb, wsdl

I have two SOAP APIs that I need to connect to through my backend API. I have two different WSDL files: commercial.wsdl and consumer.wsdl. The problem is that WBAHS120505F02327 and consumer.wsdl share XML names. When I try run the program I get the following error:

```
Two classes have the same XML type name "{https://secure.xxx.co.za/xxx}EmpiricaEM04". Use @XmlType.name and @XmlType.namespace to assign different names to them.
```

Is there a way jaxb can generate classes for both wsdl file and share the common classes? If not, is there another way around this? I am not able to change the wsdl files and have to use them as provided to me.

**Generated commercial class:
EmpericaEM04.java**

```
//
// This file was generated by the JavaTM Architecture for XML Binding(JAXB) Reference Implementation, v2.3.0 
// See <a href="https://javaee.github.io/jaxb-v2/">https://javaee.github.io/jaxb-v2/</a> 
// Any modifications to this file will be lost upon recompilation of the source schema. 
// Generated on: 2021.05.27 at 08:39:41 AM SAST 
//


package com.soap.api.xxx.commercial;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;


/**
 * <p>Java class for EmpiricaEM04 complex type.
 * 
 * <p>The following schema fragment specifies the expected content contained within this class.
 * 
 * <pre>
 * &lt;complexType name="EmpiricaEM04"&gt;
 *   &lt;complexContent&gt;
 *     &lt;extension base="{https://secure.xxx.co.za/TUBureau}Empirica"&gt;
 *       &lt;sequence&gt;
 *         &lt;element name="ConsumerNo" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string" minOccurs="0"/&gt;
 *         &lt;element name="EmpiricaScore" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string" minOccurs="0"/&gt;
 *         &lt;element name="ExclusionCode" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string" minOccurs="0"/&gt;
 *         &lt;element name="ExclusionCodeDescription" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string" minOccurs="0"/&gt;
 *         &lt;element name="ReasonCode" type="{https://secure.xxx.co.za/TUBureau}ArrayOfString" minOccurs="0"/&gt;
 *         &lt;element name="ReasonDescription" type="{https://secure.xxx.co.za/TUBureau}ArrayOfString" minOccurs="0"/&gt;
 *         &lt;element name="ExpansionScore" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string" minOccurs="0"/&gt;
 *         &lt;element name="ExpansionScoreDescription" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string" minOccurs="0"/&gt;
 *       &lt;/sequence&gt;
 *     &lt;/extension&gt;
 *   &lt;/complexContent&gt;
 * &lt;/complexType&gt;
 * </pre>
 * 
 * 
 */
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "EmpiricaEM04", propOrder = {
    "consumerNo",
    "empiricaScore",
    "exclusionCode",
    "exclusionCodeDescription",
    "reasonCode",
    "reasonDescription",
    "expansionScore",
    "expansionScoreDescription"
})
public class EmpiricaEM04
    extends Empirica
{

    @XmlElement(name = "ConsumerNo")
    protected String consumerNo;
    @XmlElement(name = "EmpiricaScore")
    protected String empiricaScore;
    @XmlElement(name = "ExclusionCode")
    protected String exclusionCode;
    @XmlElement(name = "ExclusionCodeDescription")
    protected String exclusionCodeDescription;
    @XmlElement(name = "ReasonCode")
    protected ArrayOfString reasonCode;
    @XmlElement(name = "ReasonDescription")
    protected ArrayOfString reasonDescription;
    @XmlElement(name = "ExpansionScore")
    protected String expansionScore;
    @XmlElement(name = "ExpansionScoreDescription")
    protected String expansionScoreDescription;

    /**
     * Gets the value of the consumerNo property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public String getConsumerNo() {
        return consumerNo;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the consumerNo property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public void setConsumerNo(String value) {
        this.consumerNo = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the empiricaScore property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public String getEmpiricaScore() {
        return empiricaScore;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the empiricaScore property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public void setEmpiricaScore(String value) {
        this.empiricaScore = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the exclusionCode property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public String getExclusionCode() {
        return exclusionCode;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the exclusionCode property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public void setExclusionCode(String value) {
        this.exclusionCode = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the exclusionCodeDescription property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public String getExclusionCodeDescription() {
        return exclusionCodeDescription;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the exclusionCodeDescription property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public void setExclusionCodeDescription(String value) {
        this.exclusionCodeDescription = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the reasonCode property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link ArrayOfString }
     *     
     */
    public ArrayOfString getReasonCode() {
        return reasonCode;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the reasonCode property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link ArrayOfString }
     *     
     */
    public void setReasonCode(ArrayOfString value) {
        this.reasonCode = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the reasonDescription property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link ArrayOfString }
     *     
     */
    public ArrayOfString getReasonDescription() {
        return reasonDescription;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the reasonDescription property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link ArrayOfString }
     *     
     */
    public void setReasonDescription(ArrayOfString value) {
        this.reasonDescription = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the expansionScore property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public String getExpansionScore() {
        return expansionScore;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the expansionScore property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public void setExpansionScore(String value) {
        this.expansionScore = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the expansionScoreDescription property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public String getExpansionScoreDescription() {
        return expansionScoreDescription;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the expansionScoreDescription property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public void setExpansionScoreDescription(String value) {
        this.expansionScoreDescription = value;
    }

}
```

**Generated consumer class: EmpericaEM04.java**

```
//
// This file was generated by the JavaTM Architecture for XML Binding(JAXB) Reference Implementation, v2.3.0 
// See <a href="https://javaee.github.io/jaxb-v2/">https://javaee.github.io/jaxb-v2/</a> 
// Any modifications to this file will be lost upon recompilation of the source schema. 
// Generated on: 2021.05.26 at 04:38:27 PM SAST 
//


package com.soap.api.xxx.consumer;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;


/**
 * <p>Java class for EmpiricaEM04 complex type.
 * 
 * <p>The following schema fragment specifies the expected content contained within this class.
 * 
 * <pre>
 * &lt;complexType name="EmpiricaEM04"&gt;
 *   &lt;complexContent&gt;
 *     &lt;extension base="{https://secure.xxx.co.za/TUBureau}Empirica"&gt;
 *       &lt;sequence&gt;
 *         &lt;element name="ConsumerNo" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string" minOccurs="0"/&gt;
 *         &lt;element name="EmpiricaScore" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string" minOccurs="0"/&gt;
 *         &lt;element name="ExclusionCode" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string" minOccurs="0"/&gt;
 *         &lt;element name="ExclusionCodeDescription" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string" minOccurs="0"/&gt;
 *         &lt;element name="ReasonCode" type="{https://secure.xxx.co.za/TUBureau}ArrayOfString" minOccurs="0"/&gt;
 *         &lt;element name="ReasonDescription" type="{https://secure.xxx.co.za/TUBureau}ArrayOfString" minOccurs="0"/&gt;
 *         &lt;element name="ExpansionScore" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string" minOccurs="0"/&gt;
 *         &lt;element name="ExpansionScoreDescription" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string" minOccurs="0"/&gt;
 *       &lt;/sequence&gt;
 *     &lt;/extension&gt;
 *   &lt;/complexContent&gt;
 * &lt;/complexType&gt;
 * </pre>
 * 
 * 
 */
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "EmpiricaEM04", propOrder = {
    "consumerNo",
    "empiricaScore",
    "exclusionCode",
    "exclusionCodeDescription",
    "reasonCode",
    "reasonDescription",
    "expansionScore",
    "expansionScoreDescription"
})
public class EmpiricaEM04
    extends Empirica
{

    @XmlElement(name = "ConsumerNo")
    protected String consumerNo;
    @XmlElement(name = "EmpiricaScore")
    protected String empiricaScore;
    @XmlElement(name = "ExclusionCode")
    protected String exclusionCode;
    @XmlElement(name = "ExclusionCodeDescription")
    protected String exclusionCodeDescription;
    @XmlElement(name = "ReasonCode")
    protected ArrayOfString reasonCode;
    @XmlElement(name = "ReasonDescription")
    protected ArrayOfString reasonDescription;
    @XmlElement(name = "ExpansionScore")
    protected String expansionScore;
    @XmlElement(name = "ExpansionScoreDescription")
    protected String expansionScoreDescription;

    /**
     * Gets the value of the consumerNo property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public String getConsumerNo() {
        return consumerNo;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the consumerNo property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public void setConsumerNo(String value) {
        this.consumerNo = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the empiricaScore property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public String getEmpiricaScore() {
        return empiricaScore;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the empiricaScore property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public void setEmpiricaScore(String value) {
        this.empiricaScore = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the exclusionCode property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public String getExclusionCode() {
        return exclusionCode;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the exclusionCode property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public void setExclusionCode(String value) {
        this.exclusionCode = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the exclusionCodeDescription property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public String getExclusionCodeDescription() {
        return exclusionCodeDescription;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the exclusionCodeDescription property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public void setExclusionCodeDescription(String value) {
        this.exclusionCodeDescription = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the reasonCode property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link ArrayOfString }
     *     
     */
    public ArrayOfString getReasonCode() {
        return reasonCode;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the reasonCode property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link ArrayOfString }
     *     
     */
    public void setReasonCode(ArrayOfString value) {
        this.reasonCode = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the reasonDescription property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link ArrayOfString }
     *     
     */
    public ArrayOfString getReasonDescription() {
        return reasonDescription;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the reasonDescription property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link ArrayOfString }
     *     
     */
    public void setReasonDescription(ArrayOfString value) {
        this.reasonDescription = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the expansionScore property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public String getExpansionScore() {
        return expansionScore;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the expansionScore property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public void setExpansionScore(String value) {
        this.expansionScore = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the expansionScoreDescription property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public String getExpansionScoreDescription() {
        return expansionScoreDescription;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the expansionScoreDescription property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public void setExpansionScoreDescription(String value) {
        this.expansionScoreDescription = value;
    }

}
```

**SoapConfig.Java**

```
@Configuration
public class SoapConfig {

    @Bean
    public Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller() {
        Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
        String[] packages = {"com.soap.api.xxx.commercial", "com.soap.api.xxx.consumer"};
        marshaller.setPackagesToScan(packages);
        return marshaller;
    }

}
```

I had to generate the classes seperately because if I try generating both classes at the same time it gives me an error saying the class name has already been created.

**POM.xml**

```html
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>0.14.0</version>
  <executions>
      <execution>
          <goals>
              <goal>generate</goal>
          </goals>
      </execution>
  </executions>
  <configuration>
      <args>
          <arg>-XautoNameResolution</arg>
      </args>
      <generatePackage>com.soap.api.xxx.commercial</generatePackage>
      <generateDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/java</generateDirectory>
      <schemaDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl</schemaDirectory>
      <schemaIncludes>
          <include>*.wsdl</include>
      </schemaIncludes>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

**Full Error**

```js
Two classes have the same XML type name "{https://secure.xxx.co.za/TUBureau}EmpiricaEM04". Use @XmlType.name and @XmlType.namespace to assign different names to them.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at com.soap.api.xxx.commercial.EmpiricaEM04
        at @javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSeeAlso(value={com.soap.api.xxx.commercial.EmpiricaEM04.class, com.soap.api.xxx.commercial.EmpiricaE1.class})
        at @javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSeeAlso(value={com.soap.api.xxx.commercial.AccountVerificationVA.class, com.soap.api.xxx.commercial.ComplianceIndicatorLI.class
```